# postgresql - Subquery to look for random instance following a specific instance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that looks for a row (which could contain anything) that follows a row that contains something specific.

I'm not entirely sure how best to achieve this, my initial thoughts are to write a subquery that indexes or sorts the data and somehow specify which index to output into the main query.

I wanted to include a picture to help explain, but I'm being told I'm unable to post images. As an alternative I've posted a link to a picture below of an example data set to try and illustrate what I'm trying to do (thank you to the moderation team for your understanding):

https://postimg.org/image/va7n814s9/

So hopefully now you can see the picture, I'm basically trying to get the subquery to output the green row.

Logically it will know to do this by searching the table to find instances of queue 42 (as highlighted in blue) and outputting the next row. If there are multiple instances of queue 42 I want the subquery to focus on the latest instance and ignore the previous ones.

Also FYI I will be using postgresql via NaviCat to run the query.

I hope I'm making sense with my question above, if you need any clarification please let me know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select a.*
from actions a
where a.id > (select max(a2.id) from actions a2 where a2.queue = 42)
order by a.id
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This assumes that the ordering is based on `id`.  You can also base it on the date column.

Another method uses window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             max(case when queue = 42 then id end) over () as max_id42
      from a
     ) a
where id > max_id42
order by id
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This uses `max()` with a `case`. You can also use `filter` in more recent versions of Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for answering Gordon, unfortunately I'm not getting the desired results as yet. The first method gives me null results. The second method appears to be hanging for some reason, so after a few minutes I killed it. Any pointers or alternative methods would be much appreciated. Thank you again!

Comment: @afropunk . . . The first should only return `NULL` if the highest id has `queue = 42`.  Either query should be able to take advantage of an index `a(queue, id)`.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon. I went back to it and managed to get method 1 to work eventually. I needed to add another ID filter to get it to work but I oversimplified the question originally so you couldn't have known that! I essentially used your logic so thanks again for your speedy and helpful responses. BTW I've just discovered the blog and am finding it very interesting! All the best.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm trying to apply this logic to a larger query, and am having trouble getting it to work. Perhaps you might understand why as I'm all out of ideas. What I would like to do it for the master query to repeat this above indexing check multiple times. Unfortunately however I join this logic to the master query, it always runs once on the first list and then stops, however I'd like it to keep repeating this until it has gone through all lists in the master query. It's related but perhaps I should post another question on the site? If mods would prefer this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @afropunk . . . You should consider asking another question, with sample data and desired results and other information.

Comment: Thanks again, I posted a followup question linked below. Was wondering if you could please take a look and let me know if you think what I'm trying to do is possible? Nobody else seems to be able to answer the question! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676364/postgresql-subquery-to-look-for-random-instance-following-a-specific-instance