# postgresql - Subquery to look for random instance following a specific instance. Not working as part of master query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Just to clarify for moderation etc, this is a follow up from my previous post below:

[postgresql - Subquery to look for random instance following a specific instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619775/postgresql-subquery-to-look-for-random-instance-following-a-specific-instance)

That question was resolved however I now need to include that answer as part of a larger query and need to ask another question due to difficulties getting this to work.

The previous query enabled me to extract the green line, as highlighted by the image below, in a single list of data:

https://postimg.org/image/va7n814s9/

I now need to loop this subquery whilst working through a number of specified lists until my master query has completed a few specific counts. Regrettably when trying to achieve this the master query kept executing this subquery only once rather than looping through all the lists. I tried to code this in a number of different ways including CTE and derived tables styles, however no matter how I structure it the results are the same. This leads me to believe I might need to code the subquery slightly differently for the master query to know to keep repeating the subquery condition.

For clarity here is an example of the latest code I have so you can see exactly where I'm going wrong (edited to include code and remove link to code, my apologies relatively new to posting here):

```
SELECT table_1.agent
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=1 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_1
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=2 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_2
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=3 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_3
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=4 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_4
FROM historic_table table_1 JOIN current_table table_2 ON table_1.reviewid=table2.id
                            JOIN (SELECT table_1a.*
                                    FROM historic table_1a
                                   WHERE table_1a.id >(SELECT MAX(table_1b.id) 
                                                         FROM historic table_1b
                                                        WHERE table_1b.queue=42)
                                ORDER BY table_1a.id FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) next_instance ON table_1.id=next_instance.id
WHERE table_1.currenttimestamp>=(current_date-7)
GROUP BY table_1.agent
```

Many thanks in advance again for your help, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: Post the code here as text not elsewhere as image.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Thank you for the constructive comments, I've edited the post above to include the code in text and have removed the link to the code as instructed. Apologies for this, I had previously done this and had a question answered without any issues. I hope this is suffice and meets all the  guidelines to get a question answered, anything else please let me know. Also I have a -1 next to the question, I have done a lot of research and have revised my points to ensure they are clear explaining everything as clearly as I can. Can you please revise this?

Comment: with those 2 joins you only limit your result set, last join limits it to only 1 row, I assume table_1::id is a PK, that doesn't match your claim of looping over subquery or anything like that

Comment: Thanks Adam, yes you are correct there are two ids, the historic table has an action id and current table has an id for a review (which could contain any number of actions). What I'd like it to do is check for the pattern in the subquery for every review, and then include all thise reviews in the counts specified in the main query. At the moment it just does this for the first review that meets the subqueries conditions.

Comment: @AdamPopkiewicz Sorry Adam forgot to notifyyou on my last comment so doing that now. If you or anyone else have any ideas to try out, unfortunately still no joy trying to get this to work.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What are you trying to loop through?  Where do the non-green lines comes from?

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look @GordonLinoff! So the master query is going through reviews which all have a unique ID. They also have multiple actions IDs (which is what the sub-query was working with) as they move between queues. The looping part was for each review ID, to loop the sub-query (history of actions) find that instance pattern specified and then use only those review IDs in the master query counts. The non-green lines are examples of historic actions. Problem is when I run it as a subquery it only outputs the first row and doesn’t continue to complete the counts.

Comment: Perhaps the derived tables approach I've used here is not correct, I just thought I'd post an example as it's not very easy to explain in words. To put it another way I'm essentially trying to just get counts each time that subquery is true. Do you think I could perhaps include the subquery in each case statement? Never really done that before but might solve the 1 row output problem.

Comment: You can include a derived table with the list of ids you want to "loop" through, and let the database do the looping.

Comment: @Gordon would it be possible to post some pseudo code, like the one I posted above, so I can understand the logic and work through it with the database at my end. I tried to code it just now but didn't really understand exactly how to structure it, and it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after a lot of trial and error I managed to write the following code to give me the results set I wanted:

```
WITH alpha AS 
(SELECT table1a.urid, (SELECT MIN(table1b.classifier) FROM historic_table table1b WHERE table1b.urid=table1a.urid) AS min_agent
   FROM historic_table table1a 
  WHERE table1a.queue=42
    AND table1a.tstamp>=(current_date-7))
,stats AS
 (SELECT a.min_agent AS name
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=1 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_1
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=2 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_2
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=3 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_3
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN table2.queue=4 AND table2.status=0 THEN table2.id ELSE NULL END)AS count_4
    FROM current_table table2 JOIN alpha a ON table2.id=a.urid
GROUP BY a.min_agent)
   SELECT s.*
         ,s.count_1+s.count_2+s.count_3+s.count_4 AS total_count 
     FROM stats s 
 GROUP BY s.name
         ,s.count_1
         ,s.count_2
         ,s.count_3
         ,s.count_4 
  HAVING (s.count_1+s.count_2+s.count_3+s.count_4)>0 
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```